# CSS - Mobile image resize

Tags: css

The method I am currently using is to add `<img src="A-Button-Image.png" style="width:100%;">` in HTML sheet and the image size could scale up and down depends on the screen size.

However, **A-Button-Image.png** contains two images, hover and normal status. Thus, I'd like to use background-position to trigger the rollover effcts? Is there a way to using CSS to control background-position but without losing image resize ability? I know there is another solution is onmouseover & onmouseout, but I still prefer CSS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make the background-size to 100% and padding-bottom to percentage.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `background-size` property for your needs. Just set it to 200% and you will get both scalability and spriteability.

[See for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/XCUTE/).

You could even use more than two images in your sprite. You will just need to multiply a number of images by 100% and put the result in a `background-size` property.

Comment: Thanks! but it doesn't display the image, once text is removed. and  `display:inline-block;` isnt working

Comment: That's only because I've set the element's height in %, but since by default the document's body is as tall as the content inside, I had to put a text inside. In a real case scenario you will most certainly put your icon in an element that will have height greater than 0 so it will work just fine.

See the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/XCUTE/1/ . I've added the rule for body and html to fill all the window space. Now you don't need any text.